# Android Maps Activity memory issue

Tags: java, android, google-maps, memory

I'm making an app with a google maps activity and I display overlays and markers on it. The markers are clickable and they go to another activity with info about the location. From this activity the user goes back to the map activity. When testing this and going back and forth between the map activity and the info activity, around the 8th time going back to the map activity it crashes. Upon further investigation with the profiler in Android Studio I noticed that whenever I go back to the map activity, there is a big increase in memory usage that doesn't go back down. It's like every time you reopen the maps activity it reloads everything that I initiate in the onCreate call on top of what it previously loaded in. Which would be strange as I don't destroy the MapS activity when going to the info activity, so it shouldn't reload all the images and variables. The profiler also says that the Maps activity is just stopped and not destroyed.
[image: Profiler of reopening the Maps activity.]
I tried using MapS.super.finish when going back to the main menu to see if GC would free up the memory, but it doesn't.

**MapS activity**;

```
public class MapS extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private Location mLastKnownLocation;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;
    private final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 18;
    private View mapView;
    private Overlay[] floor0;
    private Overlay[] floor1;
    private int height = 120;
    private int width = 90;
    private HashMap<String,Bitmap> icons = new HashMap<>();
    Circle mapCircle = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);


        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.MapS);
        assert mapFragment != null;
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mapView = mapFragment.getView();

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = getFusedLocationProviderClient(MapS.this);
        Places.initialize(MapS.this, ("MY API KEY GOES HERE"));

HERE I DEFINE SOME BUTTONS AND I CREATE MY OVERLAY OBJECTS (THESE CONTAIN A BITMAPDESCRIPTORFACTORY,COORDINATES AND SOME INTEGERS)

WHEN THE BUTTONS GO TO ANOTHER ACTIVITY THAN THE INFO ACTIVITY OF A LOCATION, I DO MapS.super.finish() TO DESTROY THE MAPS ACTIVITY

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 51) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                getDeviceLocation();

            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        GET DEVICE LOCATION
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.clear();

        //This is the part that initializes the overlays and the markers
        //display floor 0 at the start
        HERE I HAVE THE CODE THAT ADDS THE OVERLAYS TO THE MAP? LET'S THE USER SWITCH BETWEEN FLOORS AND ADDS THE MARKERS, IT ALSO CHECKS IF THE USER IS INSIDE A CERTAIN RANGE OF A MARKER AND IF SO HE CAN CLICK THE MARKER AND GO TO IT'S INFO ACTIVITY


    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim the code

Comment: Marcin, is it better now?

Comment: Yes, that's better, thanks. In general: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed the biggest issue as it's now workable and in the profiler there doesn't seem to be a big memory issue. hen going from the map activity to the info activity I didn't clear the map, so when the user returned to the map it reloaded everything on top. When using LeakCanary I still get a leak warning though:
**Report LeakCanary:**

```
┬───
│ GC Root: Global variable in native code
│
├─ com.google.android.gms.internal.location.zzat instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ zzat.zzda
│           ~~~~
├─ com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.ListenerHolder instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ListenerHolder.zajk
│                     ~~~~
├─ com.kulak.discoverkoelak.MapS$8 instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Anonymous subclass of com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback
│    ↓ MapS$8.this$0
│             ~~~~~~
╰→ com.kulak.discoverkoelak.MapS instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.kulak.discoverkoelak.MapS received Activity#onDestroy() callback and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
​     key = 7b56a75c-cafa-4963-8d7f-27eb78fb3efc
​     watchDurationMillis = 5131
​     retainedDurationMillis = 128
```

If anybody knows what is causing this feel free to answer underneath this question.

Comment: I am not sure if you found a solution to this but make sure you release all map Ui-related items in onDestroyView(), so that means you need to initialize the map object like this;

`private var _map: GoogleMap? = null
  private val map get() = _map!!`

And set the _map as null in OnDestroyView, also clear the locationCallback